# Combining rows of data with the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a query that SELECTS from 5 different tables:

```
SELECT  R.[Name],
        P.[Name],
        S.[Number],
        T.[Name],
        D.[Hours],
        D.[ActivityDate]
FROM DailyTaskHours D
INNER JOIN Task T
    ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task
INNER JOIN Story S
    ON T.StoryId = S.PK_Story
INNER JOIN Sprint P
    ON S.SprintId = P.PK_Sprint
INNER JOIN Product R
    ON P.ProductId = R.PK_Product
```

This is what the results look like visually:
[image]

The last two columns are called Hours and ActivityDate. As can be seen on the table, for Number - OPA-76 there are two entries:

[image]

Instead of two rows I would like it to be one row. I would like there to be 7 columns instead of the last two labeled Sunday through Saturday and the two entries for hours go in the correct day of the week based on their ActivityDate.

There can be only 1 entry per day.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Would this be for only the next seven says, or any date that falls on a sunday would be shown?

Comment: I will be restricting the query to specific weeks as parameters via a UI. So any date that is a result of this query will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT R.[Name], P.[Name], S.[Number], T.[Name],
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
   sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(dw, D.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN D.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday
FROM DailyTaskHours D
INNER JOIN Task T ON D.TaskId = T.PK_Task
INNER JOIN Story S ON T.StoryId = S.PK_Story
INNER JOIN Sprint P ON S.SprintId = P.PK_Sprint
INNER JOIN Product R ON P.ProductId = R.PK_Product
GROUP BY R.[Name], P.[Name], S.[Number], T.[Name]
```

Read the note about weekdays here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: I am getting the following error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: paste your whole query here